# Why does @Published not work in NSManagedObject?

Tags: core-data, swiftui, combine, nsmanagedobject, observableobject

`@Published` publishes correctly when used in an `ObservableObject`. But does not seem to publish when used in an `NSManagedObject` (which conforms to `ObservableObject`).

In the following example when using `Data1` the text below the picker is updated. But using `Data2` it is not. Why is that?

```swift
import SwiftUI
import CoreData

class Data1: ObservableObject {
    @Published var direction: Direction = .left
}

class Data2: NSManagedObject { // NSManagedObject conforms to ObservableObject
    @Published var direction: Direction = .left
}

enum Direction {
    case left
    case right
}

@main
struct SwiftUITestApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView().environmentObject(Data2()) // Or Data1() as needed
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject private var data: Data2
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Picker("", selection: $data.direction) {
                Text("Left").tag(Direction.left)
                Text("Right").tag(Direction.right)
            }.pickerStyle(.wheel)
            switch data.direction {
            case .left:
                Text("Selected: Left")
            case .right:
                Text("Selected: Right")
            }
        }.padding()
    }
}
```

Comment: *`NSManagedObject` conforms to `ObservableObject`* means that all @NSManaged properties publish by default.

Comment: @vadian I expect it to publish because of `@Published`, not because the variable is inside an `NSManagedObject` subclass. The question is why does `NSManagedObject` break `@Published`.

Comment: So you are adding a property to your NSManagedObject subclass that is not defined in the corresponding entity, is this correct?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Yes, that is correct as this property should not be stored in Core Data.

Comment: In Core Data you can mark an attribute to be transient, meaning it will be part of your class but not persisted. You should try this to see if it gets published the same way as an ordinary attribute

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I tried a transient attribute and it does get published. If you add an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to add a transient Core Data attribute. Transient attributes are published but not persisted.

Alternatively, you can publish changes like this:

```swift
class Data2: NSManagedObject {
    @Published var direction: Direction = .left { // @Published is optional
        willSet {
            objectWillChange.send()
        }
    }
}
```